# Cycle the CPU [Android]

Tags: android, cpu, performance-testing, stability

I have the source for a benchmark test for Android, and I would like to modify it a bit.

As of right now, the benchmark test presumably runs the CPU at full load (100%), what I want to do is pause the benchmark test (or something similar in nature) to let the CPU cool down to a lower load percentage (maybe 10% or 20%) and then run the CPU at 100% again, doing this over and over.

How does one approach this problem?

Comment: It depends on the sources.

Comment: Is there no general use case? I'm calling `Thread.sleep()` to pause the benchmark (for 3 minutes) but the stock CPU measurements (Show CPU usage from Developer Tools in Android) don't seem to be going down at all.

Comment: So yes, in general you need to stop thread which loads CPU. But you need to know which exactly thread(or threads) do this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue of not being able to "cycle" the CPU was unrelated to `Thread.sleep()`, which @Fox suggested, but in regards to calling `System.exit(0)` in my activity instead of calling finish(). I don't know why, but it works as expected.

Anyone wanna explain why the CPU dials down after calling `System.exit(0)`? Maybe threads still running?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following on a program with no separate  threads created

```
    try 
     {
        // thread to sleep for 1000 milliseconds
        Thread.sleep(1000);
     }
     catch (Exception e) 
     {
          System.out.println(e);
     }
```